# Java to PHP - return JSON but receives HTTP 406 response

Tags: java, php, json, http

I'm struggling with some Java code that works fine when executed correctly on my localhost, but, fails with an HTTP response of 406 when executed through my web server.  I've tried to read up on 406 error codes, but, I'm stuck on the fact that the code works fine locally.  The intent of the code is to send a request to the web server via HTTP to execute a back end PHP program.  There are no parameters required with the HTTP request.  The PHP program retrieves some data from an SQL data base and returns it to the Java program via JSON.  This all works fine when run locally (eg. via "localhost").  Here's the latest incantation of the code...

```
//  preparation
String charset = "UTF-8";
String szURL = new String ();
int responseCode = 0;

if (!debugConfiguration)
    szURL = "https://secure.justhost.com/xxxx.php";  // removed actual file name
else
    szURL = "http://localhost/xxxx.php";             // removed actual file name
//  HTTP Post request
URL object = null;
try 
    {
    object = new URL(szURL);
    }
catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

//xxxHttpsURLConnection con = null;
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try 
    {
    //xxxcon = (HttpsURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    }
catch (IOException e)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

//add request header
try 
    {
    //xxxcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }
catch (ProtocolException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

//con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
//con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
//con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
//con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream wr = null;
try 
    {
    wr = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
try 
    {
    wr.close();
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

try 
    {
    responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

BufferedReader in = null;
try 
    {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

try 
    {
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
        response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

try 
    {
    in.close();
    }
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

Gson gson = new Gson ();    
jsonArticleCategories[] enums = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), jsonArticleCategories[].class);
for (int i=0; i<enums.length; ++i)
    {
    jsonArticleCategories jac = enums[i];
    cats.add(jac.get_category());
    }
```

As you may see from the code, I've tried several variations of parameters, etc.  I'm probably missing something very basic, but, I'm just not seeing it.  Maybe I've been staring at the code too long.  I would appreciate it very much if someone can point out my flaw(s).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the live server is sending back the `application/json` content type as well as valid JSON?

Comment: 406 indicates the server finds the request to be unacceptable for whatever reason. It would be interesting to see what actually gets pushed over the wire. Btw: A `GET` request with a set `Content-Type` header is a bit strange ... Perhaps you shouldn't set that header unconditionally?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Well, I'm not sure.  I forgot to mention that when I run the PHP code on the server by typing the same url that's in the java code, it does work correctly.  I see the requested json fields returned on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those with a similar problem. I was able to resolve this problem with the assistance of Tim B's suggestion to use the Rest test harness to delve into the HTTP aspects of my problem.  This gave me some insight into what was happening.  I then stumbled upon [this StackOveflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506363/connecting-to-mysql-from-java-using-php?rq=1) that shed some more light onto the properties that I should be sending via my applet code.  I now have the applet code calling the php code and returning the json data.  Thanks to all that offered assistance.

Answer (score 0):

NotAcceptable means that the request came in a format (for example JSON) that the server wasn't able to process. Quite a few of the Java frameworks automagically pick up and process message types by looking to see if there is a library available to handle them, maybe the PHP is doing something similar?

Use a Rest test harness and you can try sending the request yourself and focus on getting the server side working with that, then only after that add the complication of the client side code.

If you use firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/reviews/ is good. I'm sure the other browser have something similar but I've not used them myself.

Comment: "maybe the PHP is doing something similar?" I can safely say no. I'd rather think the webserver were misbehaving.